# Angular ng-repeat dynamic array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

Given a json of array of objects, how could one display it using a ng-repeat dynamically? `error` key is static / always remain the same. Just the values of `error` changes. So if I have the password field errored-out then I'll have `password` key instead on the `error`

```
{ 
  "error":  {
    "firstName": {
      "0": "The first name field is required.",
      "1": "The first name field must have 2-5 characters."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "0": "The last name field is required."
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
{ 
  "error":  {
    "password": {
      "0": "The password field is required."
    }
  }
}
```

I tried doing:

```
<ul ng-repeat="message in errormessage">
    <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in message">
         {{k}} - {{v}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it displays this instead:

```
0 - [
0 - ]
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: How come it is not a valid JSON?

Comment: Just try it with a online validator.

Comment: Try it again. There are 2 json there. Not one.

Comment: That's right then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.errormessage = {
      "error": {
        "firstName": {
          "0": "The first name field is required.",
          "1": "The first name field must have 2-5 characters."
        },
        "lastName": {
          "0": "The last name field is required."
        },
        "passowrd": {
          "0": "The password field is required."
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">

  <ul ng-repeat="message in errormessage">
    <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in message">
      <b>{{k}}:</b><br>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="err in v">
          {{err}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems weird that it is returning a string instead of an array. Something like this `{"error":{"firstName":{"0":"The first name field is required.","1":"The first name field must have 2-5 characters."},"lastName":{"0":"The last name field is required."},"passowrd":{"0":"The password field is required."}}}`

Comment: And having this error `Error: ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater` using the `track by $index` displays each letter as an array though.

Comment: it sounds like you are looping through a string instead of valid object. You may need to parse the JSON string. use `JSON.parse(YOUR_ERROR_RESPONSE)`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I think the first thing you have to consider is to normalize your json if you have control over that and represent it like this

```
$scope.errormessage = {
  "error": {
        "firstName": {
            "0": "The first name field is required.",
            "1": "The first name field must have 2-5 characters."
        },
        "lastName": {
            "0": "The last name field is required."
        },
        "passowrd": {
             "0": "The password field is required."
        },
        "mail": {
            "0": "The first name field is required.",
            "1": "The first name field must have 2-5 characters."
        },
        "newsletter": {
             "0": "The newsletter field is required."
        },
        "address": {
             "0": "The address field is required."
        }
    }
}
```

Why this because you cant have two **field named error** on a same object or array. After this the first solution provided must work

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="message in errormessage">
       <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in message">
         <b>{{k}}:</b><br>
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="err in v">
             {{err}}
            </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the ng-repeat on the right object. You have:

```
ng-repeat="message in errormessage"
```

and the content of `errormessage` seems to be `"[]"`. See http://jsfiddle.net/hgk6vsqv/

Comment: Better to explain what is needed to make it work, than to set up a demo of something not working. They already have a non-working version

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- **`Given a json of array of objects`**. Your `JSON` is not an `array of Objects`.
- Try this `ng-repeat="message in errormessage.error"` instead of `ng-repeat="message in errormessage"`

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.errormessage = { 
  "error":  {
    "firstName": {
      "0": "The first name field is required.",
      "1": "The first name field must have 2-5 characters."
    },
    "lastName": {
      "0": "The last name field is required."
    }
  }
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul ng-repeat="message in errormessage.error">
    <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in message">
         {{k}} - {{v}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```